# Laravel Mix - Set different plugins options per entry

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

Is there any way to provide different plugin options for each entry?

For example:

```
mix
.sass('resources/assets/main.scss', 'public/css/main.css').options({
   //Set purifycss config options for main style (Mainly different paths)
   purifyCss: {},
})
.sass('resources/assets/admin.scss').options({
   //Set purifycss config options for admin style
   purifyCss: {},
})
```

I have already tried the above configuration and purifyCss options are shared and not seperated.

Comment: You can use different css or sass or plugin just you need role management and there will be different plugin for each user according to their role

Comment: Please note that this is basically the same plugin i just need different path for each entry name

Comment: it is also same you can put different path with role management it doesnot matter

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to?

Comment: aaah  it takes a long time and it it will change database structure if you use role management , i have question about why you want different path for same plugin, is it changing something with different path

Comment: What it has to do with database?
Sometimes you want purge different path based on the entry name
On admin styles i would like to purge admin paths and so on..

Comment: oohh Sorry I got your question with wrong meaning so my answer is for another situation not yours